# Problems with null pointer using mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a method. And in this method, a new Object is instancied, but I don't want it, otherwise other class will be tested.
How I tell to mockito dont intanciate it?

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class VerificadorDeNovasAssinaturas { 

    private DocuSign docuSign;
    private ApiClient apiClient;
    @Autowired
    private DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties;

    public EnvelopesInformation verificaNovasAssinaturas() throws Exception {
        this.docuSign = new DocuSign(docuSignProperties); // I don't want mockito instanciate DocuSign
        this.apiClient = docuSign.getApiClient();
        this.apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + docuSign.getoAuthToken().getAccessToken());
```

And my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class VerificadorDeNovasAssinaturasTest {

@InjectMocks
private VerificadorDeNovasAssinaturas verificador;

private DocuSignProperties docuSignProperties;
private ApiClient apiClient;
private UserInfo userInfo; 
private OAuthToken oAuthToken;

@Mock
private DocuSign docuSign;


@Before
public void initialize() throws Exception {
    docuSignProperties = new DocuSignProperties();
    docuSignProperties.setBaseUrl("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
    docuSignProperties.setBasePath("/restapi");
    setApiClientConfigurations();
    when(docuSign.getApiClient()).thenReturn(this.apiClient);        
    when(docuSign.getoAuthToken()).thenReturn(this.oAuthToken);
    ...}

private void setApiClientConfigurations() throws Exception {
    this.apiClient = new ApiClient(this.docuSignProperties.getBaseUrl());
    this.oAuthToken = getOAuth();
            ... }
 @Test
 public void testaVerificacaoDeNovasAssinaturas() throws Exception {
    EnvelopesInformation results = verificador.verificaNovasAssinaturas();
    assertNotNull(results);
}
```

I don't want mockito instanciate a new DocuSign, because this is not the reason of the test. There is some way do ignore this step?

Comment: Pure `mockito` can not help you here. You could use `powermockito's` `whenNew` functionality to replace it with a mock. Otherwise you will have to refactor your code to provide `DocuSign` as a dependency instead.

Comment: maybe something like this  if you want to call real methods from mock object other than the mocked methods.      Stock MOCK_STOCK = Mockito.mock( Stock.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS );

Comment: With mockito, the only thing that you can do is have the `new DocuSign(docuSignProperties);` returned by a separate method, which you can mock. But anyways, I'd like to know where you're getting a null pointer as is right now.

Comment: You can use mockito to mock the stubbed object's method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I resolved it using powerMockito.

DocuSign docuSign = PowerMockito.mock(DocuSign.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(DocuSign.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(docuSign);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, Mockito can not change something if your code( Code to be tested, Which you intend to) does something, However you can mock it so that it does not create a new object (rather have your "Mocked Object"), so that you can verify something against the expected behavior.

In your code if you change few lines , you can achieve what you want, like -
Create a DocuSignService class and there you create this new object in say some - getDocuSign method. Then your code looks something like below -

```
@Autowired
private DocuSignService docuSignService ;

this.docuSign = new DocuSign(docuSignProperties); // This is what you have
this.docuSign = this.docuSignService.getDocuSign() ; // This is new code
```

Now in your test case -

```
@Mock
DocuSignService docuSignService ;
@Mock
private DocuSign docuSign;
//.
//.
Mockito.when(this.docuSignService.getDocuSign()).thenReturn(docuSign);
```

Now you have control on this object.